# jQuery calculation in table td loop

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, html-table

I am getting the JSON data through PHP. I am trying to calculate the value of `td` with the help of javascript and jQuery and calculate the opening and closing balance as below like the table example.

is this possible to do that?
Please help me How I implement with jquery in my jQuery code.

**Example table -**

`open bal as 0 first time` + `today in` - `today out` = `closing bal` and
`previous closing bal` will be `open bal next day`.

| open bal | today in | today out | closing bal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 2 | 0 | 2 |

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
  },
  success: function(response) {
    if (response == "ok") {
      $.each(response.data, function(i, items) {
        tableWithHeader.find('tbody').append(`
     <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>${items.inqty}</td>
      <td>${items.outqty}</td>
      <td></td>
      </tr>
    `);
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: From your description I have no idea what table and what data you are currently have as result and what data and table you want as result. You shown populated table and said: `"displaying that data as given below jQuery code in the loop"` **AND**  `I am trying to calculate as given below table example"` So what excalty we should to do with this? And how about you attach sample data from response ? And also why simply not calculate in front end after you populate it if you do not know inside loop?

Comment: I updated the question. Please check is that right ? I am trying to calculate the td value as opening and closing in my ajax response

Comment: I asked for sample data... And what is inside `items.closeqty` and `items.openqty` now? You say you want to calculate those columns and yet you are populating them with those variables from json data?

Comment: I am sorry, I understand what you saying... Question Updated. pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
  },
  success: function(response) {
    if (response == "ok") {
      let openqty = 0 // declare outside of loop
      let closeqty = 0 // declare outside of loop
      $.each(response.data, function(i, items) {
      
      closeqty = parseInt(items.inqty) - parseInt(items.outqty) + openqty
      //calculate closeqty
        tableWithHeader.find('tbody').append(`
     <tr>
      <td>${openqty}</td>  // this will be 0 on first run
      <td>${items.inqty}</td>
      <td>${items.outqty}</td>
      <td>${closeqty}</td>
      </tr>
    `);
      });
      openqty = closeqty // now set it for next loop to be same as closeqty 
    }
  });
```

**Working example:**

```js
//$.ajax({
//type: "POST",
//cache: false,
//},
//success: function(response) {
//if (response == "ok") {
let openqty = 0 // declare outside of loop
let closeqty = 0 // declare outside of loop

const response = {
  data: [{
    inqty: "2",
    outqty: "0"
  }, {
    inqty: "0",
    outqty: "1"
  }, {
    inqty: "1",
    outqty: "1"
  }]
} // sample data

$.each(response.data, function(i, items) {

  closeqty = parseInt(items.inqty) - parseInt(items.outqty) + openqty
  //calculate closeqty

  $("table").find('tbody').append(`
     <tr>
      <td>${openqty}</td>  // this will be 0 on first run
      <td>${items.inqty}</td>
      <td>${items.outqty}</td>
      <td>${closeqty}</td>
      </tr>
    `);
  openqty = closeqty // now set it for next loop to be same as closeqty

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: this is work if any number comes negative ?

Comment: @Satyam I believe so yes, its normal minus plus math, but it will work properly only as long as numbers are integers, hence `parseInt()` function. If you have decimal values you will need to change code.

Comment: @Satyam Also please take note of sample data and working snippet. If you prepare question like this you will have much more chance of getting help. See what [mre] means. Welcome to SO and good luck.

Comment: I have an issue I am fetching the JSON data `ORDER BY  ASC` but when I use `DESC ORDER` the output comes wrong. Please hemp how I fix this in siuation?

Comment: @Satyam Ordering things has no impact whatsoever on calculations I made in my anwser, line by line will be calculated properly. Seem to me like totally different problem. Try opening a new question. And i don't know what you are ordering, and asked for sample data couple of times. Make sure you include all that in next question.

Comment: I updated the question and revert the table data please help me

Comment: you know everything in coding and I don't understand what you want to ask, but as I understand I am trying to give you I answer. but please help me once again as last.
I am trying to revert the function. when I use your code it good working and giving output `https://ibb.co/sQ6b1p5` is my output screenshot.but I want to like this `https://ibb.co/N2CrSqk` but here your code wrong. please help me. this is my real output come from server. `mscorpres.com/jsonfile.json`

Comment: @Satyam I do not know how you are getting result from first picture. My code result is this: https://jsfiddle.net/ikiK_Cro/rwdxcan9/1/   I just took your json data and add it. And i see nothing wrong with it.